Try as he may/might, he couldn’t open the door

Try as he may, he couldn’t open the door.


Try as he might, he couldn’t open the door.

Is there any slight difference in meaning between these ones?

Same meaning, possiblly some speakers prefer one or the other. My pref is for the second, but I think that's just opinion.

I'd reserve 'try as he may' for the present and future and use 'try as he might' for the past.

Also, I would probably reserve 'might' for hypotheticals. Try as they might, a thief wouldn't be able to steal my car. I have a strong lock on the steering wheel.

The two words are interchangeable in this use, as evidenced by the child's poem, "Wish I may, wish I might,
Have the wish I wish tonight."
Personally, I would use "might", but the reason has nothing to do with grammar. Another meaning of "might" is "strength", and when used in proximity to being unable to perform a task, creates an image of having applied a great deal of strength to the task. This is, of course, entirely a happy accident divorced from the rules of language.

I don't agree. The present tense may doesn't go with the past tense couldn't.

But might is normally used as a conditional future indicator. Wouldn't that make it improper to use with couldn't?

That may be one possible use, but it is also used for a possibility in the past. "He might have been able to open the door if the lock hadn't seized up".
